# How to unlock and root a Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray ST18i with 4.1.B.1.13

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-ray

I searched it a while and found some articles regarding **rooting the Xperia Ray** but I couldn't understand them easily. So I want help from you geeks who can give me the lighted way with simple steps to root my phone.

I found [this article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2115892) from xda-developers.com but it sais there, that I have to have an "unlocked bootloader" which I probably don't have if I haven't done anything with my phone yet, have I?
And it tells me to "wipe the dalvik-cache" which I don't see anywhere (probably after unlocking the bootloader?). I also heard something of "fastboot", but I didn't get what it is :-?

I already gct the IMEI by entering `*#06#` into my phone and got the developer **unlock code** from [unlockbootloader.sonyericsson.com](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/).

I have running the actual Ice-Cream 4.0.4 Build-Number 4.1.B.1.13, Kernel 2.6.32.9-perf

---

EDIT:
right now I am following the instructions from [Sony's Instructions on how to unlock bootloader](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/instructions). Entering the code `*#*#7378423#*#*` shows, that the unlock is allowed. I am downloading the huge Android SDK right now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I followed [these instructions](http://www.android-hilfe.de/sony-allgemein/415804-how-root-rechte-fuer-alle-bekannten-sony-android-handys-mit-fast-allen-firmwares.html) for a "one-click ROOT"

I downloaded

Eroot 1.3.4: [Link](http://www.share-online.biz/dl/3EXNWGQMREEB)

stopped all applications and started the **eroot** program

clicked on "-Root"

waited the 4 steps and there it was.
(don't press again the "Root" button, that will remove root again)

you can check with the [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) App if you have root access, click on "Verify Root Access"

If you have root access you can install a CyanogenMod release shown in the following steps (source: mainly the [CyanogenMod Wiki Howto](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_urushi#Unlock_your_Xperia_Ray) starting from step "Obtaining the Bootloader Unlock Code"):

.

### 1. Download **CyanogenMod**

1. [Download the desired *CyanogenMod*](http://get.cm/?device=urushi) and place it on your SDcard as ZIP file (currently the latest for ST18i is 10.0 which is named just cm-10-2013-NIGHTLY-urushi.zip )
   I chose `cm-10-20131007-NIGHTLY-urushi.zip`
   This takes some minutes...
2. [Download *Google Apps](http://goo.im/gapps)** for the CyanogenMod you selected (You have to install a 3rd-party app to get the Google apps, like Gmail, Play Store, and Youtube.)
   I chose [`gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip`](http://goo.im/gapps/gapps-jb-20121011-signed.zip)

   .

### 2. enable **fastboot**:

[Download Files for Fastboot](http://androidtweak.in/downloads/xperia/unlock_xperia_arc_bootloader.zip)  (the same as the Xperia arc)

1. Extract the file to a new folder naming say Unlock. (Do it neatly as you won't get confused while entering into CMD).
2. Go to [unlockbootloader.sonyericsson.com](http://unlockbootloader.sonyericsson.com) (We will do the unlocking in the official way).
3. Read the instructions carefully and click Continue/Proceed whatever they ask, note down your IMEI (The place where the website asks to paste it, enter in the exactly first 14 digits, **not 15 digits**) and after submitting your name, IMEI and email click Submit and note down the code they produce (copy that into a notepad).
4. Enter in **fastboot mode** (Don't turn on the device, just press Volume up and connect USB cable simultaneously to your PC. A blue light should come up, otherwise something has gone wrong).
5. Install the drivers for your device on your computer (from the unzipped drivers folder you downloaded)
6. Go to the fastboot directory and Ctrl+Shift+Right Click (or on Windows 7 open a CMD shell end go into the fastboot directory)
7. Type in
   `fastboot.exe -i 0x0fce getvar version`
   and hit enter
8. Type in
   `fastboot.exe -i 0x0fce oem unlock 0x<your_code>`
   (use  directly by your code that you have already copied in notepad)

You are done. When you start your phone you will have fresh factory reset but rooted Android.

.

### 3. install **ClockworkMod**:

1. Install [x-Parts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pvy.CWMinstaler) from Google Play.
2. After installation, open the app and select the Installs tab.
3. Select Install CWM and follow on-screen instructions.
4. You can **Reboot into the recovery mode** from there (press the button in the Tools Tab)

.

### 4. install **boot.img**:

Now you need to install the `boot.img` from the CyanogenMod Zip you downloaded:

1. Connect your device into fastboot again with Vol-Up While plugging in the USB-Cable
   `fastboot devices`
   (Seeing your serial number means we know all is good.)
2. Now type these commands:

   `fastboot erase system -w`
   `fastboot erase boot`
3. then copy the boot.img in the same folder as fastboot.exe and type

   `fastboot flash boot boot.img`
   `fastboot reboot`
4. Now press the Vol-Down Button to enter the Recovery Mode again and install your image

.

### 5. Install **CyanogenMod** in Recovery Mode:

1. Once the device boots into the ClockworkMod Recovery, use the physical volume buttons to move up and down. On most devices, the power button is used to confirm your selection, although for some devices the power button is used as a "back" button to go up one level, in which case the home button is used to confirm the selection.
   *Optional/Recommended: Select backup and restore to create a backup of the current installation on the Xperia Ray.*
2. Select the options to "wipe data/factory reset" and "wipe cache"
3. Select "Install zip from sdcard"
4. Select Choose the CyanogenMod zip from sdcard.
5. Select the CyanogenMod file you placed on the sdcard. You will then need to then confirm that you do wish to flash this file.
6. Install the Google Apps package as well

   Optional: Install any additional packages you wish using the same method.

Once the installation has finished, return back to the main menu, and select the reboot system now option. The Xperia Ray should now boot into CyanogenMod.

Whenever you want to re-enter the recovery-mode from now on (after installing ClockworkMod) you can always:

> press the volume down key a few times when your phone boots up. The sony logo brightens at one point, press during that time

At first, I was stuck with an error at the end:  I [Cannot install any Custom ROMs on Xperia Ray ST18i: assert failed: getprop Status 7](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55961/cannot-install-any-custom-roms-on-xperia-ray-st18i-assert-failed-getprop-statu)
but that is covered here now

Answer (score 1):

**Unlock bootloader**

With a locked bootloader, one cannot install custom roms.To gain power over bootloader one should unlock it.

Now this is the most simple and easy way to get ye bootloader by following small simple steps.

[Download Files for Fastboot](http://androidtweak.in/downloads/xperia/unlock_xperia_arc_bootloader.zip)

1. Extract the file to a new folder naming say Unlock.(Do it neatly as you wont get confused while entering into CMD).
2. Go to unlockbootloader.sonyericsson.com (We will do the unlocking in the official way).
3. Read the instructions carefully and click Continue/Proceed whatever they ask,note down ye IMEI (The place where the website ask to paste it,enter in exactly first 14 digits,not 15digits) and after submitting ye Name, IMEI and mail click Submit and note down the code they produce(Copy that in a notepad).
4. Enter in fastboot mode(Press Volume up and connect USB cable simultaneously and blue light should come up,otherwise something has gone wrong).
5. Install the drivers for your device from the drivers folder
6. Go to fastboot directory and Ctrl+Shift+Right Click (or on Windows 7 open a CMD shell end go into the fastboot directory)
7. Type in
   `fastboot.exe -i 0x0fce getvar version`  and hit enter
8. Type in
   `fastboot.exe -i 0x0fce oem unlock 0x<your_code>`
   (use  directly by your code that you have already copied in notepad) and hit Enter

You are done. When you start your Phone you will have fresh factory reset Android.
*Note: Official method says about installing latest Android SDK package which is of  more than 60MB and this method will do everything within 20MB via downloading the file which I mentioned at the beginning*

**Rooting**

In order to root do the following.

Prerequisites:
1.[Flashtool](http://androxyde.github.com/index.html?1363323556000)
2.[Kernel](http://androidtweak.in/downloads/xperia/ST18i_4.1.A.0.562_kernel.ftf)
3.[Rooting Toolkit](http://androidtweak.in/downloads/xperia/DooMLoRD_v1_Xperia-2011-ICS-ROOT-emu-busybox-su.zip)
4.Go to settings > Security > Mark ”Unknown sources”
5.Settings > Developer options > Mark USB debugging
6.[Kernal](http://androidtweak.in/downloads/xperia/ST18i_4.1.B.0.587_Kernel.ftf)

A. Trying to flash the Kernel(4.1.A.0.562) with the help of Flashtool, download and install the software. Copy the FTF file and go to the Flashtool folder you extracted. Paste it inside the ‘firmware’ folder.

B. Launch the software and click the ‘Flash’ button (the button with the lightning icon.). Select the ‘Flashmode’ option and click OK.

[image]

1.Once you are done with installing new kernel, restart your device. Rooting toolkit will let you root your device (make sure you are done with prerequisites 4 and 5).

2.Rooting your mobile via Rooting toolkit is very simple. Click on the .bat file and follow the on-screen instructions. Your mobile may restart more than twice, never mind it. Once you see “You are done” in the command mode, disconnect your device and make sure you see Superuser icon in menu.

3.Step 6 in prerequisites is purely optional and if you want to update your kernel after rooting you can repeat step 1 with 4.1.B.0.587 Kernel.

**Summary**

As there is no direct way to root your ICS built Smartphone (xperia ray) ,this is a different approach in which flashing a kernel which enables us to root mobile in a single shot. That is we flash 4.1.A.0.562 kernel, do necessary steps in rooting and then revert it to latest kernel by flashing 4.1.B.0.587.At the end of the day we will have an ICS built Ray with latest kernel inside with SU permission.

**Unroot**

If you want to unroot your mobile, then after flashing kernel with 4.1.A.0.562 download [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=765523&stc=1&d=1319922620) and run the .bat file after extracting it to some location. This script will remove the SU files and make it unrooted so that you could bring back the guarantee thing.

**Source:
[1](http://androidtweak.in/rooting/unlock-bootloader-of-2011-xperia-smartphones/),[2](http://androidtweak.in/rooting/xperia-ray-running-ics/)**

**NOTE: I'm not responsible for any of your act. Do this at your own RISK**