# Xperia ray can't root

Tags: rooting, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

Model number: ST18! , Android Version: 4.0.4 , Build number: 4.1.B.0.431

I tried to root my device (following the steps lined out in [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/41548/16575)), but it did not work.

Flash Tool Log:

```
06/027/2013 11:27:14 - INFO  - <- This level is successfully initialized

06/027/2013 11:27:14 - INFO  - Flashtool Version 0.9.10.1 built on 2013-01-09 19:49:47
06/027/2013 11:27:14 - INFO  - You can drag and drop ftf files here to start flashing them
06/027/2013 11:27:19 - INFO  - Device disconnected
06/027/2013 11:27:25 - INFO  - Selected Xperia Ray_ST18i_4.1.A.0.562_kernel.ftf
06/027/2013 11:27:25 - INFO  - Preparing files for flashing
06/027/2013 11:27:25 - INFO  - Please connect your device into flashmode.
06/027/2013 11:27:33 - INFO  - Device connected in flash mode
06/027/2013 11:27:33 - INFO  - Opening device for R/W
06/027/2013 11:27:33 - INFO  - Reading device information
06/027/2013 11:27:34 - INFO  - Phone ready for flashmode operations.
06/027/2013 11:27:34 - INFO  - Current device : ST18i - CB511UNT57 - 1252-3629_R1I - 1248-9545_4.1.A.0.562 - WORLD-i_4.1.B.0.431
06/027/2013 11:27:34 - INFO  - Start Flashing
06/027/2013 11:27:34 - INFO  - Processing loader
06/027/2013 11:27:34 - INFO  -     Checking header
06/027/2013 11:27:34 - INFO  -     Flashing data
06/027/2013 11:27:37 - INFO  - Loader : S1_Loader_Root_773f - Version : R4A066 / Bootloader status : ROOTED
06/027/2013 11:27:37 - INFO  - Processing kernel.sin
06/027/2013 11:27:37 - INFO  -     Checking header
06/027/2013 11:27:37 - INFO  -     Flashing data
06/027/2013 11:27:39 - INFO  - Ending flash session
06/027/2013 11:27:39 - INFO  - Flashing finished.
06/027/2013 11:27:39 - INFO  - Please unplug and start your phone
06/027/2013 11:27:39 - INFO  - For flashtool, Unknown Sources and Debugging must be checked in phone settings
06/027/2013 11:27:39 - INFO  - Device connected in flash mode
```

DooMLoRD_v4_ROOT Log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
              Easy rooting toolkit (v4.0)
                   created by DooMLoRD
        using exploit zergRush (Revolutionary Team)
   Credits go to all those involved in making this possible!
---------------------------------------------------------------
 [*] This script will:
     (1) root ur device using latest zergRush exploit (21 Nov)
     (2) install Busybox (1.18.4)
     (3) install SU files (binary: 3.0.3 and apk: 3.0.6)
     (4) some checks for free space, tmp directory
         (will remove Google Maps if required)
 [*] Before u begin:
     (1) make sure u have installed adb drivers for ur device
     (2) enable "USB DEBUGGING"
           from (Menu\Settings\Applications\Development)
     (3) enable "UNKNOWN SOURCES"
           from (Menu\Settings\Applications)
     (4) [OPTIONAL] increase screen timeout to 10 minutes
     (5) connect USB cable to PHONE and then connect to PC
     (6) skip "PC Companion Software" prompt on device
---------------------------------------------------------------
 CONFIRM ALL THE ABOVE THEN
Press any key to continue . . .
--- STARTING ----
--- WAITING FOR DEVICE
* daemon not running. starting it now *
* daemon started successfully *
--- creating temporary directory
mkdir failed for tmp, File exists
--- cleaning
--- pushing zergRush
1325 KB/s (23060 bytes in 0.016s)
--- correcting permissions
--- executing zergRush

[**] Zerg rush - Android 2.2/2.3 local root
[**] (C) 2011 Revolutionary. All rights reserved.

[**] Parts of code from Gingerbreak, (C) 2010-2011 The Android Exploid Crew.

[-] Not a 2.2/2.3 Android ...
--- WAITING FOR DEVICE TO RECONNECT
if it gets stuck over here for a long time then try:
   disconnect usb cable and reconnect it
   toggle "USB DEBUGGING" (first disable it then enable it)
--- DEVICE FOUND
--- pushing busybox
2698 KB/s (1075144 bytes in 0.389s)
--- correcting permissions
--- remounting /system
mount: permission denied (are you root?)
--- checking free space on /system
61 KB/s (439 bytes in 0.007s)
df: /mnt/secure/asec: Permission denied
--- Free space on /system : 60844 bytes
--- no cleanup required
--- copying busybox to /system/xbin/
/system/xbin/busybox: cannot open for write: Read-only file system
--- correcting ownership
Unable to chmod /system/xbin/busybox: No such file or directory
--- correcting permissions
Unable to chmod /system/xbin/busybox: No such file or directory
--- installing busybox
/system/bin/sh: /system/xbin/busybox: not found
--- pushing SU binary
failed to copy 'files\su' to '/system/bin/su': Read-only file system
--- correcting ownership
Unable to chmod /system/bin/su: No such file or directory
--- correcting permissions
Unable to chmod /system/bin/su: No such file or directory
--- correcting symlinks
rm failed for /system/xbin/su, Read-only file system
link failed Read-only file system
--- pushing Superuser app
failed to copy 'files\Superuser.apk' to '/system/app/./Superuser.apk': Read-only
 file system
--- cleaning
--- rebooting
ALL DONE!!!
```

I'm very new to android. But I know something about MS-Dos.
I tried to do DooMLoRD_v4_ROOT works manually, using adb shell.
But the mount command - mount: Operation not permitted.
Can anybody help me.
How can I root may device?

Thank you

Comment: Have you followed the steps described [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/41548/16575)?

Comment: That's it. Those are the steps I followed. But it didn't work. Rooting Toolkit is not working. I copied and past its log, above.

Comment: I included this fact with your question, so it's clear to possible helpers. One note: Your device runs 4.0.4, with build number 4.1.B.0.431 according to your question. The other user had build number 4.1.B.1.13. It might be that's making the difference. But not having a Sony device, I have to jump off here and leave the solution to somebody else.

Comment: Thanks for answers. But suddenly it rooted. I don't know the reason. I tried it more than 100 times. Nothing changed, but finally it worked. If another one read this because of the same problem I suggest to refresh **USB debugging** , just tick and untick for few times.

Comment: @ErandaGunathilaka Okay, then I would suggest you add that as answer and mark it as the answer to your question. It sounds like it was a non-issue?