# How to root Sony Ericsson Xperia ray?

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-ray

Here are the information of my device.
Android version : 4.04
Kernel version:  2.6.32.9
Build Number:   4.1.B.0.587
Plz give step by step method and essential material downloading link. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked [How to unlock and root a Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray ST18i with 4.1.B.1.13](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/41548/16575)? Doesn't that work for your ray anymore?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2118343) is the step by step to root your devices! BTW, Xda is the good place to start with.