# How do I install a custom ROM on sony experia ray ST18i?

Tags: custom-roms, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

I unlocked the bootloader and rooted the device already like this:
[How to unlock and root a Sony Ericsson Xperia Ray ST18i with 4.1.B.1.13](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/55944/22975) But How can I install a custom Rom now on the device?

I guess I have to enter the recovery menu for it?

I tried this, but it doesen't work:

> press the volume down key a few times when your
>   phone boots up. The sony logo brightens at one
>   point, press during that time

Comment: OP: Check out the LegacyXperia project which is designated for Sony 2011/2012 devices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [drivers](http://androidtweak.in/downloads/xperia/unlock_xperia_arc_bootloader.zip) and then install ClockworkMod with help of **x-Parts** from Google Play to enable the recovery menu

Comment: I do not recommend x-Parts as it does not work properly! The OP might be better off using LegacyXperia which contains the Clockwork Mod Recovery built in.