# Cannot install any Custom ROMs on Xperia Ray ST18i: assert failed: getprop Status 7

Tags: cyanogenmod, installation, recovery-mode, sony-ericsson-xperia-ray

When I try to install any of the roms of that page: http://get.cm/?device=urushi I always get this error:

> Finding update package... Opening update package... Installing
>   update... assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "ST18i"||
>   getprop("ro.build.product") == "ST18i"||  getprop("ro.product.device")
>   == "ST18a"|| getprop("ro.build.product") == "ST18a"||   getprop("ro.product.device") == "urushi" ||
>   getprop("ro.build.product") == "urushi" E:Error in
>   /sdcard/cm-9.1.0-urushi.zip
>   (Status 7) Installation aborted.

This sounds to me, that the prop doesen't get the right string "ST18i" which is strange, cause that's exactly my model.

Do I have to downgrade or install something else first?

I also tried to install the old image Xperia Ray (ST18i)_4.0.2.A.0.42_CE.zip again, but there is just sais "installation aborted".

Are there different Rescue Menues? I read, someone tried reinstalled his rescue menu with Odin.

I installed my Recovery Mod with the app **x-Parts** from Google Play that app installs the CWM.

Comment: Using a program like `7-zip`, you can open the script in the META-INF folder and remove that `if` or `assert` conditional which is preventing you from installing this script, or, on the actual device itself, even modify your `/system/build.prop` so that it reflects the requirements of the script.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the boot image that is included in the Cyanogenmod ZIP file an flash that in fastboot:

Connect your device with Vol-Up While plugging in the USB-Cable

```
fastboot devices
```

Seeing your serial number means we know all is good.

Now type these commands:

```
fastboot erase system -w
fastboot erase boot
```

then copy the boot.img in the same folder as fastboot.exe and type

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
fastboot reboot
```

Now press the Vol-Down Button to enter the Recovery Mode again and install your image